# Assign a task to a group - task not created, email not sent

Tags: 2013, workflow, groups, tasks

I am using a custom workflow and I have created two groups:

- Group A - composed by me;
- Group B - composed by my superior.

There is a "Assign task" action in my workflow. It is assigning the task to "Group A", but it does not send anything to my email, nor creating the task.

If I assign the task directly to myself, it works, but when I assign to the group, it does not.

Where did I go wrong?

I have tried [those steps](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13754/sharepoint-task-assignment-email-doesnt-send-to-group) but it did not work.

Comment: Is it On prem or O365?

Comment: It's Office 365

Comment: Hows the User Profile Service and do you have that sync'd properly with your OU? Also is the "Group" an active directory security group, distribution group, or SharePoint group?

Comment: Sharepoint group... I don't know what is a User Profile Service, or the other two types of groups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering that you are using a SharePoint group and presuming that the **Assign a task** step is not running inside an App Step, then make sure that **everyone** can view the membership of the group.

Go to the group settings page and the select **Everyone** option under the "*Who can view the membership of the group?*" question.

The reasoning behind this is that the workflow initiator cannot email the members of a group who he cannot see.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of task actions in SharePoint Designer: 'Assign a task' and 'Start a task process'. The former is only meant to assign a task to a single person. The latter is meant to assign a task to multiple people and therefore has the ability to expand SharePoint groups. In your case you want to "Start a task process" and then assign it to a SharePoint group. It's up to you whether to have the tasks created serially (one at a time) or in parallel (all tasks created at once).

Comment: I can't use `Start a task process` because it doesn't return the task ID, since it creates multiple tasks.

Comment: I have created a reusable workflow and assigning the task to a group is now working, I'm not sure why tho.